# How to translate "Thank you for having told me the truth" into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I know that "thank you for your help" could be translated by "gratias tibi ago ob/propter auxilium (tuum)" but I can't figure out how to deal with a preposition with a verb in it as in

> Thank you for having told me the truth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious approach is the conjunction **quod** + indicative, which is frequently employed after *gratias agere*, so you'd get:

> Gratias tibi ago, quod verum mihi dixisti.

Examples for this are all over the place, e.g. in Cicero: *tibi ago gratias, quod me omni molestia liberasti* ([ad fam. 13,62](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fam13.shtml#62)) and countless other examples.

Another option would be to use a relative clause in the subjunctive:

> Gratias tibi ago, qui verum mihi dixeris.

This makes sense and is suggested by Georges (German-Latin), but I could not immediately find any examples.

By the way, while I see nothing wrong with *ob* or *propter*, the usual preposition of choice seems to be *pro*.

Comment: By the way, you could also say: *Vere locuto tibi gratias ago*, or, if we want to get real fancy: *[Veridico](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dveridicus) tibi gratias ago.*

Comment: In "gratias tibi ago, qui verum mihi dixeris", what benefit is conferred by using a subjunctive? Relatives usually take the indicative unless there is a specific need for a subj., at least, that's my understanding. I recall "servum misit quem fidissimum haberet", TKR's translation of, "He sent the most loyal slave whom he had." (North & Hillard) and A & G secct. 278 (b): "servum misit quem secum habebat" = "He sent the slave whom he had with him.". I did ask if both subjunctive & indicative uses were correct but didn't get a reply (2019). Any thoughts, please?

Comment: @tony The function of the subjunctive here is to confer a causal sense on the relative clause. (The subjunctive might just as well confer a concessive/adversary sense, e.g. *… qui numquam verum mihi dixeris* = “… **even though** you never told me the truth.” Which is it? You have to infer that from context. So really the function of the subjunctive in relative clauses is simply to say: “This clause does not just add some information about something in the main clause. There is some deeper connection, though you have to guess what it is!”)

Comment: In that 2019 Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11316/1982, referred to above, I tried, "servum misit, qui fidissimus esset, quos possidebat (omnium servorum)." = "He sent the slave, who was the most faithful, (of all the slaves) whom he owned." I used "possidebat", indicative, because it refers to the antecedent (the slave-owner), not the most faithful slave. In this dual relative-clause structure, is the subjunctive, "esset", correct? What if indicative, "fuit", had been used?

Comment: The subjunctive, "esset", is required because it is a quality of the antecedent that is being described, A & G section 535.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. - It's been more than 50 years since my high school Latin classes, but I'll take a stab at it. Here goes ...

Dictu mihi veritatem tibi gratias ago.

Just sayin'.

Comment: What is *dictu* supposed to be? It looks like a supine, but that wouldn't exactly fit grammatically.

Comment: Yes, "dictu" is a supine form, as in "mirabile dictu" - that last phrase is usually translated into English as "wonderful to say". My old Latin text mentioned that a more literal translation might be "wonderful in the saying", although it is awkward to express it that way in written or spoken English. I took the old textbook at its word in its explanation. So, a nearly verbatim translation - and following its word order from Latin, an awkward translation into English would be: "In saying to me the truth, to you thanks I give." Again, awkward English, but I believe it is good Latin.

Comment: I am also making the assumption that it's OK for the supine form "dictu" to have an object in the accusative case, namely "veritatem". After more than 50 years, I do try to remember the correct vocabulary and grammar.

Comment: I believe it cannot have an object, but the real problem is that the second supine is [extremely limited](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/supine) in how you can employ it, it is basically restricted to adjectives like your *mirabile dictu*, *turpe factu* etc., plus the nouns *fas*, *nefas* and *opus* (e.g. *fas est memoratu*, it is allowed to bring up).

Comment: *in saying* - you'd actually want a gerund for that, not the supine. That would make this grammatical.